# Apache Flink - Can not create Hourly/Daily Log File with Log4j

Tags: java, log4j, apache-flink, logback

I can not create daily and also hourly log file (especially for taskexecutor log) with log4j

Here is the my log4j.properties

```
# This affects logging for both user code and Flink
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Uncomment this if you want to _only_ change Flink's logging
#log4j.logger.org.apache.flink=INFO

# The following lines keep the log level of common libraries/connectors on
# log level INFO. The root logger does not override this. You have to manually
# change the log levels here.
log4j.logger.akka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO

# Log all infos in the given file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${log.file}
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.file.append=false
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
```

${log.file} points to :

```java
2020-02-13 17:40:51,105 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskManagerRunner       -     -Dlog.file=/.../flink-1.9.1/log/flink-tarantula-taskexecutor-0-...log
```

- In the meantime there is a logback.xml configuration also(which one flink uses ? )
- logback.xml file :

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${log.file}</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{60} %X{sourceThread} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- This affects logging for both user code and Flink -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </root>

    <!-- Uncomment this if you want to only change Flink's logging -->
    <!--<logger name="org.apache.flink" level="INFO">-->
        <!--<appender-ref ref="file"/>-->
    <!--</logger>-->

    <!-- The following lines keep the log level of common libraries/connectors on
         log level INFO. The root logger does not override this. You have to manually
         change the log levels here. -->
    <logger name="akka" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.hadoop" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- Suppress the irrelevant (wrong) warnings from the Netty channel handler -->
    <logger name="org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline" level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

- here is the flink/lib folder
  `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar  flink-dist_2.11-1.9.1.jar  flink-table_2.11-1.9.1.jar  flink-table-blink_2.11-1.9.1.jar  log4j-1.2.17.jar  slf4j-log4j12-1.7.15.jar`

### Solution Finally

After all tried, I found the solution, I could not create daily log file because of this statement was blocking creating daily file(s).

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline=ERROR, filelog4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
```

#### Example of creating logs at midday and midnight of each day.

```
log4j.category.org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline=ERROR, nettyFileAppender
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Uncomment this if you want to _only_ change Flink's logging
#log4j.logger.org.apache.flink=INFO

# The following lines keep the log level of common libraries/connectors on
# log level INFO. The root logger does not override this. You have to manually
# change the log levels here.
log4j.logger.akka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO

# Log all infos in the given file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.file=${log.file}
log4j.appender.file.append=false
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-a
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n

# Suppress the irrelevant (wrong) warnings from the Netty channel handler
log4j.appender.nettyFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.nettyFileAppender.file=/path/to/nettyLog/nettyChannelIrrelevant.log
log4j.appender.nettyFileAppender.append=false
log4j.appender.nettyFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.nettyFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how you provide your `log4j.properties` file. But a common issue is that someone has this file in their jar, and it gets ignored, because Flink will use the `conf/log4j.properties` file located on the cluster.

And assuming your jar doesn't include anything other than classes from the `slf4j-api` jar, then Flink will pick up the `slf4j-log4j12.jar` in `flink/lib` (since that's on the classpath), and thus use `log4j` (not logback), so the `logback.xml` configuration file is ignored.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I have found log file that reads my log4j.properties: `2020-02-15 20:10:16,838 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/.../flink-1.9.1/conf/log4j.properties`. And also I am not adding jar file, I am just starting flink cluster via ./start-cluster.sh to see daily/hourly log file are creating or not. My aim is to create daily/hourly log file without submitting job from dashboard.